# What are the consequences of a dual national leaving Australia using an expired Australian passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, uk-citizens, dual-citizenship, australian-citizens

I am leaving Australia on a soon to expire/expired Australian passport but I am booking a one-way flight using my valid UK passport. Will I be allowed to leave showing my expired Australian passport? Will they confiscate my expired Australian passport?

I entered Australia before the 6-month validity expired using my Australian passport. I have no way of renewing my passport in Australia as I am not resident here and I have had an extended holiday staying with my daughter.

Comment: You are an Australian national, and you are physically present in Australia. Why cannot you [renew your Australian passport](https://www.passports.gov.au/getting-passport-how-it-works/passport-renewal)?

Comment: Why not show your unexpired UK passport on departure?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica the UK passport won't have any visa or residence permit associated with it.  I don't know whether this is in fact a problem because I don't know how Australia runs its exit controls, but it's certainly a possible cause for concern.

Comment: Relevant but not quite a duplicate: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/leaving-australia-as-a-dual-national-but-without-an-australian-passport

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation a fee years back and called up DIBP, and I was informed that while they strongly recommended against it, **we would have been allowed to leave Australia on a second passport**.  Details here:
https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/6078/181

However, in our case we still had a valid RRV in the second passport, so in the event Immigration didn't even notice when we left the country using it.  (The RRV should have been cancelled when we became citizens, but had not been.) In your case, however, leaving on a different passport will certainly be flagged.